# Automatically insert values into tables with relationships

Tags: typescript, rest, typeorm

I have two entities: customer and cart. There's a relationship between them(one-to-one). They both have primary columns with the same values. I want to insert value into the other table after I insert one into the customer's table. How can I do this?

```
@Entity()
export class Cart extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  customerId: number;
  @OneToOne((type) => Customer)
  @JoinColumn({name: 'customerId'})
  customer: Customer;
  @OneToMany((type) => CartItem, (item) => item.cart)
  @JoinColumn()
  items: CartItem[];
  @UpdateDateColumn()
  date: string;
}

@Entity()
export class Customer {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;
  @Column({ unique: true })
  username: string;
  @Column()
  password: string;
  @OneToOne((type) => Cart, {cascade: true})
  cart: Cart;
  @OneToOne((type) => CustomerInfo, {cascade: true})
  info: CustomerInfo;
}
```

Comment: Show what you have done to relate the two entities

Comment: I've just added code to the question.

Comment: `Cart` probably shouldn't have `customerId` as its primary column.  You should be able to relate the two entities through reciprocal `cart: Cart` and `customer: Customer` mappings without the need to specify the join column (unless there is a specific reason to override the default convention). With appropriate `cascade` options then a single save should commit the graph in one go.